# If or statements in python

Tags: python

```
wow = ["wowza this is a really long string wows"]

if "long"  or "is" in wow:
    print("yes")
```

output is `yes`

however if I put in

```
wow = ["wowza this is a really long string wows"]

if "long" in wow:
print("yes")
```

output is `nothing`

same with:

```
 wow = ["wowza this is a really long string wows"]

    if "is" in wow:
    print("yes")
```

why?

I thought `or` was supposed to be either one?
but if individually inputed both are false but with `or` it becomes true?

or that's the wrong way to write an `if or statement?`

should it be written like this?

```
if "long" in wow or "is" in wow:
```

Comment: [Python 3 Operator Precedence Table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: `'long'` is `True` and thus the expression will always be `True`.

Comment: This question has been asked so many hundreds of times. Why do people keep writing new answers to it instead of just marking it a dup?

Comment: @abarnert Reputation try-hards.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Don't you lose the rep once the question is closed? (I'm actually not sure about that; I've never bothered to go search on meta, but I always assumed there was no rep gain or loss for answering good duplicates, garbage questions, or anything else that's going to be closed.)

Comment: @abarnert No. You get what you get unless downvoted.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Ah, now I understand a little better the people who downvote everyone who answers a bad question…

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Thanks for rewarding contributors wish such kind words. Perhaps it would make more sense to automatically append their answers to the original post instead, once you mark a question as duplicate? Oh, no, it wouldn't work: then the answers would lose context. But that would mean context is important, and this means it is also useful to answer duplicates within their original context, for the benefit of the person who posted the duplicate.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, I don't feel obliged to search for original answers when paying a poster the favour of answering their questions. Thank you for performing that work for me.

Comment: @dmvianna Actually I didn't downvote or mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if "long"  or "is" in wow:
```

is equivalent to

```
if ("long")  or ("is" in wow):
```

What you want is:

```
if "long" in wow or "is" in wow:
```

The first test is successful, because `"long"  or "is" in wow` returns `"long"` and the string `"long"` is truthy*. The following tests fail, because `wow` is a list with 1 string, and the `in` operator tests for list containment here, instead of string containment.

*the `or "is" in wow` part would not get tested here, because the if short-circuits. Has nothing to do with your problem though

Comment: thank you. I got confused with these or statements

Comment: I thought `if "long"  or "is" in wow:` was returning true because we are checking `if "long"  or "is"` which is True.

Comment: @Scott the `in` operator has higher priority than the `or` operator. [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: @Felk `in` over `or` thanks for educating me.  So the first line then is really doing `'is' in wow` which is False, then `if 'long' or False:...` which is True.

Answer (score 4):

OK, we have several different problems here.

```
if "long"  or "is" in wow:
```

That means this:

```
if ("long")  or ("is" in wow):
```

So yes, you need to change it to this:

```
if "long" in wow or "is" in wow:
```

But that still doesn't do what you want, because `wow` is a list.  You're asking whether `"long"` is an element of that list.  But `"long"` isn't an element of the list.  The only element of the list is the string `"wowza this is a really long string wows"`, which is not the same as `"long"`.  You want to check against the string itself, not the list.

Comment: thank you. I got it all cleared now. Yes I should've checked it against the string itself not the list. thank you again very much

Answer (score 4):

How about you send your condition to the interactive prompt (run python or ipython if you have it) to see what it returns?

```
>>> wow = ["wowza this is a really long string wows"]
>>> "long" in wow
False
>>> "long" or "is" in wow
'long'
```

You probably want to test the string, not a single item list:

```
>>> wow = wow[0]
>>> "long" in wow
True
>>> "long" or "is" in wow
'long'
>>> ("long" or "is") in wow
True
>>> wow
'wowza this is a really long string wows'
```

Comment: thanks for that. It's just the or operator I was confused at.

and yes I should've used a string instead of a list. thank you. I needed some clarification. thank you very much for taking the time to educate everyone